# Galois extentions

Tags: galois-theory

> 1. If $F \subset K \subset E$, with $E/K$ and $K/F$ galois, then $E/F$ is galois.
> 2. If $F \subset K \subset E$, with $E/F$ galois, then $E/K$ and $K/F$ are galois.
>    $\def\less{\smallsetminus}$

For the first one: $E/F$ is galois because $E/K$ is galois you can extend an automorphism $\delta$ on $F$ to an automorphism $δ'$ on $K$ such that $δ'(α) \neq α$  for $α \in K \less F$. And in a similar way for elements in $E \less K$. Therefore there is an automorphism on $E$ which permutes all elements not in $F$.

How would I prove the second one is right or wrong?

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: Good try at LaTeX. You can edit to see how we improved it. =)

Comment: Thank you, I was on my mobile phone so doing it in Latex wasn't easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Gal(E/F)$ is abelian, then the second statement is true.
In general case, $E/K$ is Galois, given $E/F$ is. This is the statement of Fundamental Theorem of Galois theory.
However $K/F$ needn't be Galois if $Gal(E/F)$ is not abelian.

Let $E$ be the splitting field of $x^{3} - 2$, an irreducible polynomial, over $\mathbb{Q} = F$ and let $K =  \mathbb{Q} (2^{1/3})$. Then $E$ is Galois over $F$ , because it's the splitting field of a polynomial,hence over $K$ as well,  However $K/F$ is not a normal extension (Why?)  , hence not Galois.

Comment: Because not all the zeros of the polynomial are in K.

Comment: Just a minor quibble: to see that $E/K$ is Galois, you do not need the fundamental theorem. Being Galois is equivalent to being a splitting field of a family of separable polynomials (or equivalently, being normal and separable); and this can be checked directly.

Comment: @knsam In Dummit and Foote , that's one of the 4-5 statements making up the  fundamental theorem and that's what i was referring to.  Of course , like you pointed out, one can directly prove the same fact.

Comment: @ironfeliks Oops, OK, "my version" of the fundamental theorem is just the Galois correspondence. As I said, that was a minor quibble. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don’t make clear just what your question is. I presume, though, that you’ve been asked to say whether your two statements are true or false; and if false, show a counterexample.

Galoisness, in fact, normality, is not a tower property, that is, a normal extension of a normal extension is not necessarily normal, and the standard example is $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2\,)$. The big field isn’t normal over $\Bbb Q$ ’cause it doesn’t contain the root $i\sqrt[4]2$ of $X^4-2$. The two separate layers are normal because they’re quadratic, and every quadratic extension is normal.

But you’ve made a statement in your attempted proof of the first proposition that might be a common misapprehension. You seem to say that an automorphism of the subfield $F$ can be extended to an automorphism of the Galois extension $K$ of $F$. This is emphatically not true. Take the automorphism of $F=\Bbb C(z)$ that sends $z$ to $z+1$, so takes a rational function $q(z)$ to $q(z+1)$. And take $K=\Bbb C(z^{1/2})$, a quadratic extension, so Galois. But $(z+1)^{1/2}\notin\Bbb C(z^{1/2})$, that is, the automorphism I’ve specified can’t be extended to the extension field.